# Usar método de outra classe

Tags: java, android, método, visibilidade

Preciso executar um método que está em outra classe. Acho que as duas são classes não activityes.

A classe a seguir possui um método chamado `connect()`. Quando esse método é executado, ao fim dele quero chamar um outro método que está em outra classe. A seguir está a classe que possui o método `connect()`. Cara vez que eu clicar em Conectar (botão do menu), preciso que o programa execute também o método `publish()`que pertence a outra classe.

```js
    class ActionListener implements IMqttActionListener {

      enum Action {
        CONNECT,
        DISCONNECT,
        SUBSCRIBE,
        PUBLISH
      }

      private Action action;
      private String[] additionalArgs;
      private String clientHandle;
      private Context context;

      public ActionListener(Context context, Action action,
          String clientHandle, String... additionalArgs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.action = action;
        this.clientHandle = clientHandle;
        this.additionalArgs = additionalArgs;
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
        switch (action) {
          case CONNECT :
            connect(); 
            break;
          case DISCONNECT :
            disconnect();

        }

      }


      private void disconnect() {
        Connection c = Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle);
        c.changeConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED);
        String actionTaken = context.getString(R.string.toast_disconnected);
        c.addAction(actionTaken);

      }


      //Daqui quero executar outro método em outra classe
      private void connect() { 

        Connection c = Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle);
        c.changeConnectionStatus(Connection.ConnectionStatus.CONNECTED);
        c.addAction("Client Connected");

         }


      @Override
      public void onFailure(IMqttToken token, Throwable exception) {
        switch (action) {
          case CONNECT :
            connect(exception);
            break;
          case DISCONNECT :
            disconnect(exception);
            break;

        }

      }


      private void disconnect(Throwable exception) {
        Connection c = Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle);
        c.changeConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED);
        c.addAction("Disconnect Failed - an error occured");

      }

        private void connect(Throwable exception) {
        Connection c = Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle);
        c.changeConnectionStatus(Connection.ConnectionStatus.ERROR);
        c.addAction("Client failed to connect");

        Listener var = new Listener();
        var.publish();

      }

    }
```

O objeto `new Listener();` sugere os dois construtores da classe `Listener`. Sendo eles `onnectionDetails connectionDetails, String clientHandle` e `ClientConnections clientConnections`. Se deixar o construtor vazio ele retorna dá `nullpointerexception`.

`Listener.java:245` aponta para `String topic = ((EditText) connectionDetails.findViewById...`

`(ActionListener.java:163)` para `var.publish();`

`(ActionListener.java:92)` para `case CONNECT: connect();`

A segunda classe está a seguir. O método que eu quero usar é o `PUBLISH()`

```js
public class Listener implements OnMenuItemClickListener{

  private String clientHandle = null;
  private ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = null;
  private ClientConnections clientConnections = null;
  private Context context = null;
  static boolean logging = false;

  public Listener(ConnectionDetails connectionDetails, String clientHandle)
  {
    this.connectionDetails = connectionDetails;
    this.clientHandle = clientHandle;
    context = connectionDetails;
  }

    public Listener(ClientConnections clientConnections) {
    this.clientConnections = clientConnections;
    context = clientConnections;
  }

    @Override
  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id)
    {
      case R.id.publish :
        publish();
        break;
      case R.id.subscribe :
        subscribe();
        break;
          }

    return false;
  }



  private void subscribe()
  {
    String topic = ((EditText) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.topic)).getText().toString();
    ((EditText) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.topic)).getText().clear();

    RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.qosSubRadio);
    int checked = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int qos = ActivityConstants.defaultQos;

    switch (checked) {
      case R.id.qos0 :
        qos = 0;
        break;
      case R.id.qos1 :
        qos = 1;
        break;
      case R.id.qos2 :
        qos = 2;
        break;
    }

    try {
      String[] topics = new String[1];
      topics[0] = topic;
      Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle).getClient()
          .subscribe(topic, qos, null, new ActionListener(context, Action.SUBSCRIBE, clientHandle, topics));
    }
    catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
      Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to subscribe to" + topic + " the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
    }
    catch (MqttException e) {
      Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to subscribe to" + topic + " the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
    }
  }


  //Método a ser chamado 
  private void publish()
  {    

    String topic = ((EditText) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.lastWillTopic))
        .getText().toString();


    String message = ((EditText) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.lastWill)).getText()
        .toString();


    RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.qosRadio);
    int checked = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    int qos = ActivityConstants.defaultQos;

    switch (checked) {
      case R.id.qos0 :
        qos = 0;
        break;
      case R.id.qos1 :
        qos = 1;
        break;
      case R.id.qos2 :
        qos = 2;
        break;
    }

    boolean retained = ((CheckBox) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.retained))
        .isChecked();

    String[] args = new String[2];
    args[0] = message;
    args[1] = topic+";qos:"+qos+";retained:"+retained;

    try {
      Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle).getClient()
          .publish(topic, message.getBytes(), qos, retained, null, new ActionListener(context, Action.PUBLISH, clientHandle, args));
    }
    catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
      Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to publish a messged from the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
    }
    catch (MqttException e) {
      Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to publish a messged from the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
    }

  }  

}
```

Logcat:

```js
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
09-28 11:32:15.745  25770-25770/org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample, PID: 25770
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample.Listener.publish(Listener.java:245)
            at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample.ActionListener.connect(ActionListener.java:163)
            at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.sample.ActionListener.onSuccess(ActionListener.java:92)
            at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttTokenAndroid.notifyComplete(MqttTokenAndroid.java:124)
            at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.simpleAction(MqttAndroidClient.java:1370)
            at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.connectAction(MqttAndroidClient.java:1325)
            at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.onReceive(MqttAndroidClient.java:1265)
            at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
            at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
            at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mude a declaração do método publish de private para public, aí você consegue acessar de outras classes, ou pode mudar para protected, se ambas as classes estiverem no mesmo pacote:

```
public void publish() {}
```

Ou

```
protected void publish() {}
```

Então, dentro do seu método conect você cria o objeto da classe Listener e chama o método publish. Você pode ainda fazer publish ser static, aí não vai precisar criar o objeto.

Comment: Coloquei `publish()` como público. Se eu fiz certo, deixei dentro de connect o seguinte: `Listener var = new Listener(); var.publish();` Mas surgiu um erro "cannot resolved constructor Listener()" Pedindo pra criar um construtor. Tentei fazer `publish()`como Static, mas alguns itens dentro do método `publish()` ficaram vermelhos.

Comment: Você não tem nenhum construtor vazio na classe Listener pra poder criar um vazio e usar. Declare um e tente novamente:

`public Listener() {}`

Comment: Declarei um e tentei. Ao chamar o `publish()` o programa dá erro. Mas se eu colocar um `System.out.println` na `Listener` ele chama normal. Mas chamando o `publish()` dá erro. No logcat há umas mensagens, posso editar e postar pra ver se ajuda em algo.

Comment: Agora que vi, isso é provavelmente por que o método `publish()` usa o `connectionDetails` mas se você não passar uma instância dele no construtor, ele vai ser null por conta disso `private ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = null;`, ou seja, você não pode usar o construtor vazio, tem que usar o que recebe uma instância de `ConnectionDetails` e passar essa instância.

Comment: Eu compreendi o que você disse e faz sentido. Mas poderia por favor me mostrar como? Eu não consegui fazer.

Comment: Se a intenção é só usar no mesmo pacote, não precisa ser `protected`. Não usar modificador (controle de acesso padrão) já basta.